# Add SSL and lose Page Rank

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, http, ssl, https

I add SSL certificate to my web page 'https://my-motivator.pl'

I transfer all files to private catalog on my server, redirect in .htaccess all possible entries to https:// , and prepare WordPress to be response with https:// correctly. Now I check my page rank and before changes it was 2/10, now is unrank.

What should I do now? I loose my 'natural' Google entries because I lose my PR?

Comment: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6033049

Comment: Thanks - but I doesn't find information about time what I need to wait on page rank.